# My Google maps isn't always showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps

On my contact page on my website, I have a Google maps in the background. The problem is that it doesn't always show up or partially. If you go directly to the contact page ( http://jimmyhoule.net/index.html#contact ), the map will be alright, but if you go to any other pages first ( like this one http://jimmyhoule.net/index.html ) then click on "contact" in the menu on the left, the map will either be not appearing or partially there near the menu bar.

[image]

This the code I have for the map :

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// The latitude and longitude of your business / place
var position = [46.13828143498409, -72.71355827100831];
function showGoogleMaps() {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position[0], position[1]);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12, // initialize zoom level - the max value is 21
        streetViewControl: false, // hide the yellow Street View pegman
        scaleControl: false, // allow users to zoom the Google Map
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: latLng,
        scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        styles : [{featureType:'all',stylers:[{saturation:-100},{gamma:0.0}]}]
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemaps'),
        mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', showGoogleMaps);
</script>
```

I have this problem on both Firefox and Chrome (didn't test on other browsers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not another page. You are just adding a hash to your URL. Your page is testing for the hash when it loads, but the hash is not there when this happens before you click your link, so the size of your Element where `id='googlemaps'` is not to full size when your page loads without the hash. Make sure your `googlemaps` Element is full size before calling `showGoogleMaps()` on a click Event when adding your hash, as well as `if(location.hash.replace('#', '').match(/contact/i))` when your page loads.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not sur I did it exactly how you said but based on your answer, i succeed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try directly calling your `showGoogleMaps` function when the user navigates to the contacts page.